# VS2013 - Pre-build event fires before child projects are built

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

We have a requirement to build certain .EXEs to not have any external dependencies - that don't require additional DLLs to be installed, or app.config files, etc. We want a .EXE that can simply be dropped into a directory in the path, and work.

Which isn't easy, in .NET. Particularly when these .EXEs have dependencies on our own shared libraries.

Back in the day, we'd have statically linked these apps. That's not a possibility in .NET.

So, what we're doing is to embed the dependent DLLs in our .EXE, as embedded resources, and to hook in a ResolveEventHandler that loads the assemblies from the embedded resource:

```
public class AssemblyResolver
{
    static AssemblyResolver()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(Resolver);
    }

    static Assembly Resolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        string prefix = "MyNamespace.DLLs.{0}.dll";

        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        var name = String.Format(prefix, assemblyName.Name);

        var a1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var s = a1.GetManifestResourceStream(name);

        var block = new byte[s.Length];
        s.Read(block, 0, block.Length);

        var a2 = Assembly.Load(block);
        return a2;
    }
}
```

And that works fine, if we can put a copy of the DLL into the DLLs folder of our project. Which is easy enough to do, for third-party DLLs. But doing so for our own DLLs is more complicated. These are rebuilt every time we build the solution, and we want the latest build, embedded in the .EXE.

What we had been doing is to create a pre-build event that copies the DLL, prior to the project being built. That works fine, from Visual Studio. But it doesn't work when the project is built by running msbuild from the command line. When run from the command line, msbuild fires the pre-build event prior to any of the dependent projects being built, and that's too early - the DLLs we're trying to copy don't exist, yet.

So, what can I do?

Comment: Cab you show your pre-build event?

Comment: COPY "$(SolutionDir)externals\MyLib\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\MyLib.dll" "$(ProjectDir)DLLs"

Comment: 1. It would be more helpful if you include the whole xml settings for this target.